# Rewrite URL for Two Parameters using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I read many discussions related two mod rewrite using htaccess from stackoverflow. But nothing works well for me. This is my url, `www.website.com/image.php?category=animals&name=tiger` and I would like to change it into clean url as below. `http://www.website.com/animal/tiger`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ category.php?tag=$1 [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ covers.php?tag=$1&name=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

`www.website.com/animal/tiger` is working well, but when I click on (categories) `www.website.com/animal/` ,it is not showing results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're missing ending slash check in rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ category.php?tag=$1 [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ covers.php?tag=$1&name=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Please try that.